# Set union over window in PySpark

Tags: pyspark

I am trying to get the list of all unique values that appear for a certain group of IDs, and all of this over window. As for the data below, for each `address` I want to find all `id` that has common `value` and gather the set of all `value` that appear for a group of `id`.

For example, I have `window.partitionBy('address')`. For `address: 1` I see that `id: A, B, C` have common `value: x`. I understand they are connected and want to create `value_set` with all `value` that correspond with `id: A, B, C`, which is `x,y,z`.

`id: D` does not have common `value` with any other `id`, so its `value_set` include only values of `id: D`.

```
My data
+-------+---+-----+
|address| id|value|
+-------+---+-----+
|      1|  A|    x|
|      1|  A|    у|
|      1|  B|    x|
|      1|  C|    x|
|      1|  C|    z|
|      1|  D|    v|
|      2|  E|    m|
|      2|  E|    n|
|      2|  F|    m|
|      2|  F|    p|
+-------+---+-----+

What I want
+-------+---+-----+---------+
|address| id|value|value_set|
+-------+---+-----+---------+
|      1|  A|    x|    x,y,z|
|      1|  A|    у|    x,y,z|
|      1|  B|    x|    x,y,z|
|      1|  C|    x|    x,y,z|
|      1|  C|    z|    x,y,z|
|      1|  D|    x|    v    |
|      2|  E|    m|    m,n,p|
|      2|  E|    n|    m,n,p|
|      2|  F|    m|    m,n,p|
|      2|  F|    p|    m,n,p|
+-------+---+-----+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```py
dfn = df.withColumn('set_collect',collect_set(df.value).over(Window.partitionBy('address')))
```

Output is:

```py
+-------+---+-----+------------+
|address| id|value| set_collect|
+-------+---+-----+------------+
|      1|  A|    x|[у, v, z, x]|
|      1|  A|    у|[у, v, z, x]|
|      1|  B|    x|[у, v, z, x]|
|      1|  C|    x|[у, v, z, x]|
|      1|  C|    z|[у, v, z, x]|
|      1|  D|    v|[у, v, z, x]|
|      2|  E|    m|   [n, m, p]|
|      2|  E|    n|   [n, m, p]|
|      2|  F|    m|   [n, m, p]|
|      2|  F|    p|   [n, m, p]|
+-------+---+-----+------------+
```

Comment: Thanks, but nope, see the example of what I need as a result. I need to find common values, and for the IDs with common value create a set of all values these IDs have